# How to run own vps with RTCMultiConnection

Tags: webrtc

How to node **server.js** from my website like
**https://domainname.com:443/**
It's run by default from server ip or localhost like
**https://localhost:9001:/**
Or
**https://123.123.123.123:9001/**

**I want to node server.js from my domain, I have vps**
Thank you

Comment: In my opinion, the best solution is to setup following:
 - NodejS
 - Nginx with reverse proxy 
 - Lets Encrypt
 - own instance of Coturn (TURN-Server)